# How to implement an extracted XML code in HTML using Python?

Tags: python, html, xml, xml-parsing, rss

I have to extract the rss feed of a news site and show the exact news feed in my own html page. I am able to extract the xml code from rss feed.

```
import feedparser
feed = feedparser.parse('http://home.web.cern.ch/scientists/updates/feed')
for post in feed.entries:
    print (post.title + "\n")
    print (post.description + "\n")
```

But can anyone help me out, how can I implement this XML code in my new HTML page to make it look as the same news as it is on the news site. I am doing in python.

Any help is appreciated. Thanx in advance.

EDIT - I am doing for practice purpose. No violations of copyright.

Comment: What does `"... look as the same news on the news site..."` mean? Keep in mind there are copyrights related to how something may be presented.

Comment: @user590028...I am doing for practice purpose...no violations of copyright.

Comment: You still haven't answered the question, what does `"... look as the same news on the news site..."` mean?

Comment: I mean the way a single news column look like, its position along with image, etc (including the css).